# how does this callback function work

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am new to nodejs and almost n00b of JavaScript. I saw the code to create a server using nodejs. I can understand that the anonymous function is called after a request reached the server.

```
var http=require("http");
http.createServer(function(request,response){
 response.writeHead(200,{"Content-Type":"text/plain"});
 response.write("hello world");
 responde.end();
}).listen(8888);
```

My question is how to implement something similar like createServer function (foo() bar())..in order to understand how this method works.

In order to make it clear. I have done this that is not working. and how to make it work like createServer() ?

```
function dummycallback(para1,para2,callback)
{
 console.log('para1 is ' + para1+' para2 is '+ para2);
 callback();
}

dummycallback(1,2,function(req,res)
{
 req.senddata("good");
});
```

I have seen these code everywhere in nodejs so I am desperately want to know the details...thanks again

Comment: Your question is vague. Are you asking for someone to explain the internal structure and logic flow of the `http` module, or do you have a specific usage problem that you need help with?

Comment: Since this is not real question it is hard to answer. https://github.com/joyent/node/blob/master/lib/http.js#L1625

Comment: It's kind of hard to understand what you're asking. Could you maybe give another example?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe, you are asking how the anonymous function works.

```
var fun = function(foo){
    if (foo) foo(1, 2); ///< if function foo exists, call it.
}
fun(function(p1, p2){
    return p1 + p2;
});
```